# how to get history.back value in javascript

Tags: url, history

How can i get the URL of the previous page in JavaScript?
I mean the value of this function:

```
history.back()
```

or this one :

```
history.go(-1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For privacy reasons, you will never be able to do that.

Comment: what about getting the current URL ?

Comment: You mean the `location` property?

Comment: I'm new to java ,i think yes . so location.what contains the current url ?

Comment: 1) Java is to Javascript as Car is Carpet.  2) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location

Comment: thanks ,so how some websites say that i visit them from Google ?Do they use PHP codes?

Answer (score 5):

In JavaScript, you use the `document.referrer` property, which will give you the URL of the page where the user came from.